# I am getting an error advising that an expression must have constant value, Could someone help me see where I have gone wrong?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for an assessment and for a reason I cannot yet determine I get an error when I try to declare the array at a specific size. The error I get is "expression must have a constant value. I am very new to C++ coding so am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Below is my code for review.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function to calculate the sum of non-negative values in an array 
int sunNonNegative(int* arr, int size) {
    int sum = 0; // Initialize a variable to store the sum
// Iterate through the elements of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
// Check if the current element is non-negative
        if (arr[i] >= 0) {
// If the element is non-negative, add it to the sum
            sum += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return sum; // Return the sum of non-negative values`your text`
}

int main()
{
    int size;
//Asks the user to enter the size of the list
    cout << "Enter the size of the List: ";
    cin >> size;

    int list[size]; //Declares the size of the arry at a  specified size

//Prompts the user to enter the elements of the array
    cout << "Enter" << size << " elements:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cin >> list[i]; //Reads the elements from the user
    }

//This calls the sumNonNegative function to calculate the sum of non-negative values
    int result = sunNonNegative(list, size);
    cout << "Sum of non-negative-values: " << result << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure what to try next except to ask here.

Comment: The size of an array must be a compile-time constant value. It can't depend on user input. Use `std::vector<int> list(size);` instead of `int list[size];`.

Comment: Always compile with warnings enabled (also the ones that will not allow for C++ language extensions). Use : `-std=c++20 -Wall -Wpedantic  -Wextra` see https://godbolt.org/z/TPfc4EGMe. This will show you variable length arrays are not a thing in C++ and as said you should use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: A tip about writing comments: comments should describe things that aren't obvious from the code.  Most of the comments in the code in the question are stating things that are obvious. They're just distractions and should be removed.

Comment: I agree with you Pete. Unfortunately as part of the assessment we had to put comments on everything :)